# Availability of smart contracts in Etherscan?

Tags: etherscan

Are all smart contracts deployed in the Ethereum network available on Etherscan.io ?

Because I read here https://info.etherscan.com/using-smart-contract-search-tool/ that 'All ***verified*** source code can be searched using our Smart Contract Search tool....'. So does this mean that if a smart contract is deployed but not verified by Etherscan, it will not be available on Etherscan ?

Answer (score 1):

All deployed contracts exist in Etherscan and are traceable, but contracts that have been verified also give you access to the code of that contract.

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan can find any address.
There are two types of addresses:

- EOA
- contract address

[here is a biref explanation](https://medium.com/coinmonks/smart-contract-address-creation-method-difference-between-smart-contract-address-and-wallet-97b421506455)

The code of a contract is **only available as bytecode until it is verified**, which means that the creator of the contract **provided the ABI** and the code of the contract. Once the contract is verified on etherscan you can have access to the code and interact with the contract through **etherscan api** ( read and write).